# What does commit mean in the info column of processlist in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue where I ran some queries on a huge MySQL DB and now most if not all tables seem to be getting deadlocks when we query. If I do `show full processlist;` I see a lot of queries with the `state` column in `init` and the `info` column under `commit`. I believe these `commit` processes are the culprits of the locks but don't want to kill them because I do not know what side effects it might cause.

So the actual question is, what does being as commit mean?

Comment: Queries as in 'getting information'? OR 'queries as 'changing the database' You can always read 'without consistancy'. The user will need to verify the information if they change it or make decisions based on the received data. It really only applies to large tables an/ or long running queries.

Comment: My queries read from one table, did transformations and added to a different table, so kind of both?

Comment: Are you using transactions? - which you should. Do you have to 'update' the 'huge table'? I assume 'NO'.  Are you using 'quick selection criteria' against the 'huge table?

Comment: By quick selection criteria, do you mean using indexed fields? If so, yes it is over indexed fields but I do `group by` by non-indexed fields.

Comment: Let's see the queries of a transaction.  Perhaps we can make suggestions on how to speed it up.